# Recursion Reverse

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static String backwards(Integer x){
    if (x < 0){
        return "";
    }else{
        return x + ", " + backwards(x - 1);
    }
}
```

I made a method that if given a positive integer(through command line), will count from that integer all the way to 0. My question is what approach should I take to reverse this?

For example, instead of going

```
4, 3, 2, 1, 0,
```

I want it to be like so

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 8):

Just reverse the return statement, so that it produces the output from `0` to `x - 1` before it outputs `x`.

```
public static String backwards(Integer x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return backwards(x - 1) + ", " + x;
    }
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* It was that simple.....? I need to get some sleep lol Anyways, so thanks Eran

Comment: Or `return (4-x) + ", " + backwards(x - 1);` but I suspect that's not the answer expected for that assignment :)

Comment: , 0, 1, 2, 3 Was the output. The comma before the 0 is bothering me, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: NEVERMIND I got it... Another facepalm moment. Im gonna get some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly modified version to avoid a the result starting with a ",". The condition could have been "x == 0" but using "<=" avoids an extra check for a negative input value of X.

```
public static String backwards(Integer x){
    if (x <= 0){
        return "0";
    }else{
        return backwards(x - 1) + ", " + x;
    }
}
```